# dynamic linked wxwdiget program can't run

Tags: dll, wxwidgets

I compiled the wxWidgets-3.0.2 on windows using MinGW and MSYS by using

```
   configure
   make 
   make install
```

commands.

I compiled sample program successfully.  But when clicked for executing .exe it thows error **wxmsw30u_gl_gcc_custom** not found.

When I copied the executable in lib folder where .dll are stored it runs successfully.

I think program does not find the DLL paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely unrelated to wxWidgets and is just how DLLs work in Windows. To simplify a little, they must be present in the `PATH` or in the program directory (or in Windows directory but please don't put them there).